# Embed Apache Derby Database inside a Java project

Tags: java, database, servlets, derby, web-development-server

i am developing a web application project using Apache Tomcat and Apache Derby. I have successfully created an embedded database and i can connect to it. The problem is that the DB is being created/connected to a path relative to the machine in which the project is run. I want to *export the entire database* inside the Java project but i cannot understand how to do it. There are two problems:

1. In which folder should i put the Database?
2. How should i specify the path to connect with JDBC?

I have tried different approaches with `getServletContext()` and other methods but the only folder i can specify are relative to the Apache installation folder or the out artifact one.

The purpose of this operation is to make the project (that doesn't aim to production) portable, so that the Database is already present and populated.

Comment: If you've got web + db you really want an ORM technology like JPA. A typical technique is to have your application pre-populate the respository or repositories where necessary

Comment: I am developing a project not a real application. So i simply want to transfer the "ready" database from the local environment to the Java project.

Comment: You can do that too with ORM

Comment: So do you think that what i asked is not directly feasible by setting the database folder in the right location and specify the correct jdbc path?

Comment: Yes, I think it's quite possible, though I haven't done it myself. You could maybe put it in WEB-INF/storage

Comment: Having said that you would be much better off if you put it outside the web app. Otherwise your storage state will not be maintained when you redeploy

Comment: I totally agree that this is not a "realistic" approach and has different problems but i have to fulfill the request that they gave to me.

Comment: I would set it up so that Derby is working in client-server mode then you're essentially accessing by jdbc url

Comment: The data needs to be persisted in a folder somewhere. If you are deploying to Tomcat, you can create a tomcat subfolder to store the data, just for this purpose. Now, in the `context.xml` file you can define a String parameter to configure where this path is. The application will read the parameter and use it to connect/create the database in there.